# Is there a way to know if my app has been accessed by someone on heroku?

Tags: heroku

I created an app and deployed it on heroku. I have given the link to a couple of people. Is there a way to know (in the logs or somewhere else) whether they have actually opened it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terminal:

```
$ heroku logs | fgrep "heroku[router]"
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, Im using a windows machine, so fgrep does not work.

Comment: Just use `findstr` or [any of the other plentiful alternatives](http://superuser.com/q/300815/9232).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, open your application log, any request done should be in there. If you want more detailed information, use something like google analytics in your app.